# How to disable and re-enable wireless network card in Fedora?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, fedora

I have a laptop that I use mainly as as a back up, but it has a problem with the network card needing to be disabled and re-enabled from time to time. This is easy enough in Windows, but how would I go about this in Fedora (23) from the command line? I don't mean that I just want to stop the wireless connection, but actually disable the network card and re-enable it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Us these to turn **Eth0** or **Wlan0** off if these are the network interfaces you want to toggle on and off.

To turn off use:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
```

**Or**

```
ifdown wlan0
```

To turn back on use:

```
Ipconfig wlan0 up
```

**Or**

```
Ifup wlan0
```

If you install a more updated package ---> [iproute2](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2) Suggested by 
**@MariusMatutiae**

**Turn Off wlan0.**

```
ip link set dev wlan0 down
```

**Flush wlan0**

```
ip addr flush dev wlan0
```

**Restart Wlan0**

```
ip link set dev wlan0 up
```

Comment: It is best to forget obsolete utilities like `ifconfig`, and to use the current `ip` utility from the `iproute2` package.  Then the commands become `ip link set dev wlan0 down`, `ip addr flush dev wlan0`, `ip link set dev wlan0 up`.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Appreciate that I will Add this in and give you Props.

Comment: I tried the ip utility method, but got this when I tried to restart it:

'RTNETLINK answers: Input/output error'

Comment: Just to be clear, how can I make sure I'm disabling and restarting the right interface, because mine is not wlan0?

Comment: @Jefferson Check here https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/SystemdPredictableNetworkInterfaceNames

Comment: @Jefferson Pls see my answer, only to your question °Just to be clear, how can I make sure I'm disabling and restarting the right interface, because mine is not wlan0?*

Answer (score 2):

> Just to be clear, how can I make sure I'm disabling and restarting the right interface, because mine is not wlan0?

The command

```
ip link show
```

displays all your interfaces. You will have one called `lo` which is **only** an internal interface, used for IPC (=Inter Process Commnication). Among the remaining ones you can identify the wifi interface by means of

```
$ iwconfig
  eth0      no wireless extensions.

  wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

  wwan0     no wireless extensions.

  lo        no wireless extensions.
```

which shows clearly that, on my pc, `wlan0` is the only wifi interface.

If you have more than one remaining interface, like in my case, you can identify the ethernet NIC by means of

```
  sudo ethtool eth0
  sudo ethtool wwan0
```

: the ethernet interface will produce a long output, the other one will be very short. In my case, I have a wwan0 interface which is used to connect to telephone data networks,  Edge/3G/4G.